# Tengo problemas para integrar mercadopago con laravel

Tags: php, laravel, mercadopago, null

Estoy intentando agregar mercadopago a un ecommerce creado con Laravel, al momento de crear un nuevo objeto me tira un error. Ya tengo configurado el access token pero no se si lo hice correctamente.

Use el composer require "mercadopago/dx-php:dev-master"

**El error**

> "ErrorException >Trying to access array offset on value of type null >     http://localhost:8000/carrito/confirmar"

**En el controlador del carrito**

```
public function confirm() { 
$cart = session('cart'); 
\MercadoPago\SDK::setAccessToken(env('MP_SECRET'));
$preference = new \MercadoPago\Preference(); }
```

**En el composer.json**

```
"require": { "php": "^7.1.3",
 "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
 "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
 "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
 "mercadopago/dx-php": "dev-master" },
```

**La ruta**

```
Route::post('/confirm', 'CartController@confirm');
```

Comment: Estoy con algo similar. Pudiste solucionarlo?

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente es un problema con PHP 7.4. La unica "solucion" que consegui fue hacer un downgrade de la version de PHP a la 7.2.29. Sin embargo ahora obtengo otra exception, incluso cuando utilizo el package en un proyecto no Laravel.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

Comment: Segun entiendo,mi respuesta resuelve su problema. Solo le advierto que se podria encontrar con otro mas.

Comment: hola que tal yo desinstale xamp e instale xampp-windows-x64-7.2.29-0-VC15-installer pero cuando corro el composer update no instala  mercadopago/dx-php:dev-master. alguna sugerencia? Gracias

Comment: Probaste composer require? revisaste que este agregado en el composer.json?

Answer (score 0):

Estoy teniendo el mismo problema al intentar instalar Mercado Pago con composer y me da un error, se puede hacer la instalación sin composer, bajando los programas directamente del github de mercado pago

Comment: Mira Cómo responder para que tu responder sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el recorrido para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!